# how to return multiple NumPy arrays from function into separate Dataframe columns

Tags: python, dataframe

How can I return two NumPy arrays generated inside a function, back into two separate columns of a DataFrame?

I can manage to return a single NumPy array into a single DataFrame column using the two remarked lines of code, but not more than one array.

Please refer to sample code below.  The code of of the function "my_function" is kept minimal just for the example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n=2000
t=np.linspace(0.,n/200,num=n,endpoint=False)

x=0.3*np.random.normal(0,1.,n) 
y=0.3*np.random.normal(0,1.,n)
z=0.3*np.random.normal(0,1.,n)


def my_function(entry):     
    # some code here that creates two lists, for example:
    freq = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
    mag  = [5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0]
    #return np.array(freq)
    return np.array(freq),np.array(mag)


idx = pd.date_range('2020-01-01',periods=2000,freq='5L')
df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx,columns=['X','Y','Z'])
df['X']=x
df['Y']=y
df['Z']=z


features_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['frequency','magnitude'])

resample_freq ='0.5S'  # resample-frequency
#features_df['frequency'] = df[['X','Y','Z']].resample(resample_freq).apply(my_function)
features_df[['frequency','magnitude']] = df[['X','Y','Z']].resample(resample_freq).apply(my_function)

features_df.head()
```

Comment: By passing `my_function()` to `.apply()`, do you mean that the individual values in each column are numpy arrays? Or are the two arrays that `my_function()` creates the final columns?

Comment: With the above example, I'm expecting the Dataframe "features_df" to have 20 rows.

Each row for the column 'frequency' should contain an array with elements [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0].  

Each row for column 'magnitude' should contain an array with elements [5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0]

Comment: Would factoring your `my_function()` into 2 functions be an option? And then passing a dictionary with these functions as shown in the last example [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.apply.html#pandas.core.resample.Resampler.apply)?. Or just calling apply once for each column and corresponding function?

Comment: @Lennart that's what I'm doing at the moment: calling apply once for each column a corresponding function.  Since I'm calling almost same function twice (only the return statement varies), I was wondering if there's a better way around.